# hpneural parameter tuning - variable number of hidden layers (in do loop)

Tags: neural-network, sas

I prepared some train and validation sets like:

```
data train;
     retain Make Model DriveTrain EngineSize Horsepower MSRP;
     set sashelp.cars(where=(Origin <> 'Asia'));
     keep Make Model DriveTrain EngineSize Horsepower MSRP;

run;

data validation;
     retain Make Model DriveTrain EngineSize Horsepower MSRP;
     set sashelp.cars(where=(Origin = 'Asia'));
     keep Make Model MSRP DriveTrain EngineSize Horsepower;
run;
```

As for now, I build a macro to train nn model with variable number of neurons.

```
%macro build_predictions();

    data validations_scores;
        set validation;
        keep Make Model MSRP;
    run;

    %do neurons = 1 % to 10;

            proc hpneural data=train;
                input Make -- Horsepower / level=nom;
                target MSRP / level=int;
                hidden &neurons.;
                train outmodel=model_neural_network maxiter=1000;
            run;

            proc hpneural data=validation;
               score model=model_neural_network out=scored_test_data;
            run;

            data scored_test_data;
                set scored_test_data(keep=P_MSRP);
                P_MSRP = ceil(P_MSRP);
                rename P_MSRP = Forecast_neurons_&neurons.;
            run;

            data validations_scores;
                set validations_scores;
                set scored_test_data;
            run;

        %end;

%mend;

%build_predictions;
```

I would like to add second loop to go build model with 1 to 5 hidden layers. In hp procedure more layers means I need to add additional line of code. e.g. 3 layers with 5 neurons would be:

```
proc hpneural data=train;
            input Make -- Horsepower / level=nom;
            target MSRP / level=int;
            hidden 5;
            hidden 5;
            hidden 5;
            train outmodel=model_neural_network maxiter=1000;
run;
```

So basically how can I build some additinal macro that would copy from 1 to 5 times line `hidden &neurons.;`

Thanks lot!

**[EDIT]:**

I have build a macro that does it for me:

```
%macro copy_lines(i, neurons);

    %global hidden_layers;

    %if &i. eq 1 %then %do;
        %let hidden_layers = %str(hidden &neurons.;); 
    %end;
    %if &i. eq 2 %then %do;
        %let hidden_layers = %str(hidden &neurons.; hidden &neurons.;);
    %end;
    %if &i. eq 3 %then %do;
        %let hidden_layers = %str(hidden &neurons.; hidden &neurons.; hidden &neurons.;);
    %end;
    %if &i. eq 4 %then %do;
        %let hidden_layers = %str(hidden &neurons.; hidden &neurons.; hidden &neurons.; hidden &neurons.;);
    %end;
    %if &i. eq 5 %then %do;
        %let hidden_layers = %str(hidden &neurons.; hidden &neurons.; hidden &neurons.; hidden &neurons.; hidden &neurons.;);
    %end;

%mend;
```

and it works like this:

```
%copy_lines(3, 5);
proc hpneural data=train;
            input Make -- Horsepower / level=nom;
            target MSRP / level=int;
            &hidden_layers.         
            train outmodel=model_neural_network maxiter=1000;
run;
```

But I would still love to have better and more "elegant" solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second macro use a `%do` loop to emit the desired source code. In the first macro use a macro **invocation** instead of a macro variable **resolution**

```
%macro hidden_layers (layers=, neurons=);

  %local i;
  %do i = 1 %to &layers;
    hidden &neurons;   /* macro will emit this source code &layer times */
  %end;

%mend;
```

Adjust your original macro from

```
            … 
            target MSRP / level=int;
            hidden &neurons.;
            train outmodel=model_neural_network maxiter=1000
```

to

```
            … 
            target MSRP / level=int;
            %hidden_layers (3, &neurons)
            train outmodel=model_neural_network maxiter=1000
```

You could also just perform the loop inside the original macro (and not have to create a second macro).

```
%macro build_predictions
  %do neurons = 1 % to 10;
        proc hpneural data=train;
            input Make -- Horsepower / level=nom;
            target MSRP / level=int;

            %local index;
            %do index = 1 %to 3; hidden &neurons.; %end;

            train outmodel=model_neural_network maxiter=1000;
        run;
        …
    %end; %* neurons loop;
%mend;
```

In the above, you could add a parameter to the original macro, such as `%macro build_prediction (layers_count=)` and use `&layers_count` in place of 3

Answer (score 1):

You can try following approach to use a loop instead of writing same statements multiple times

```
options merror mlogic mprint symbolgen;
%macro copy_lines(i, neurons);
    %global hidden_layers_temp;
    %let hidden_layers_temp='';
    /*loop through the number of given iterations*/
    %do j=1 %to &i;
        %let hidden_layers_temp=%str(&hidden_layers_temp,hidden &neurons.;);
    %end;
    /*Remove the first 3 characters which are '',*/
    %let hidden_layers=%qsysfunc(substr(&hidden_layers_temp,4,%sysfunc(length(&hidden_layers_temp))-3));
    %put &hidden_layers;
%mend;

%copy_lines(3, 5);
%copy_lines(5, 23);
```